# BVP , NDSolve: There are fewer dependent variables, , than equations, so the system is overdetermined

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, ode

I am new to mathematica. Please help me solve this.

it is of form

```
NDSolve[ode==0,bc1==0,bc2==0,f,{R,1,2}]
```

***Edited***

> Error: Power::infy: "Infinite expression 1/0.^(11/6) encountered"
>   NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at R == 1

```
BC1 = -1 + (0.8*e5*(-1 - f[R]^2/R^2))/((f[R]^2*Derivative[1][f][R]^2)/R^2)^(5/6) 
+ 2*e5*(-1 + Sqrt[(f[R]^2*Derivative[1][f][R]^2)/R^2]) /.R -> 2

BC2 = 10 - (0.8*e5*(R^2 + f[R]^2))/(R^2*((f[R]^2*Derivative[1][f][R]^2)/R^2)^(5/6))
+ 2*e5*(-1 + Sqrt[(f[R]^2*Derivative[1][f][R]^2)/R^2]) /. R -> 1

NDSolve[{
   -((f[R]*((0.8*e5*(-1 - f[R]^2/R^2))/((f[R]^2*Derivative[1][f][R]^2)/R^2)^(5/6) + 2*e5*(-1 + Sqrt[(f[R]^2*Derivative[1][f][R]^2)/R^2])))/R^2) + 
     (Derivative[1][f][R]*((0.8*e5*(-1 - f[R]^2/R^2))/((f[R]^2*Derivative[1][f][R]^2)/R^2)^(5/6) + 2*e5*(-1 + Sqrt[(f[R]^2*Derivative[1][f][R]^2)/R^2])))/R + 
     ((f[R]*((0.8*e5*(-1 - f[R]^2/R^2))/((f[R]^2*Derivative[1][f][R]^2)/R^2)^(5/6) + 2*e5*(-1 + Sqrt[(f[R]^2*Derivative[1][f][R]^2)/R^2])))/R - 
       Derivative[1][f][R]*((0.8*e5*(-1 - Derivative[1][f][R]^2))/((f[R]^2*Derivative[1][f][R]^2)/R^2)^(5/6) + 2*e5*(-1 + Sqrt[(f[R]^2*Derivative[1][f][R]^2)/R^2])))/R + 
     (1/R)*(f[R]*((0.8*e5*((2*f[R]^2)/R^3 - (2*f[R]*Derivative[1][f][R])/R^2))/((f[R]^2*Derivative[1][f][R]^2)/R^2)^(5/6) - 
        (0.6666666666666667*e5*(-1 - f[R]^2/R^2)*(-((2*f[R]^2*Derivative[1][f][R]^2)/R^3) + (2*f[R]*Derivative[1][f][R]^3)/R^2 + (2*f[R]^2*Derivative[1][f][R]*Derivative[2][f][R])/R^2))/
         ((f[R]^2*Derivative[1][f][R]^2)/R^2)^(11/6) + (e5*(-((2*f[R]^2*Derivative[1][f][R]^2)/R^3) + (2*f[R]*Derivative[1][f][R]^3)/R^2 + (2*f[R]^2*Derivative[1][f][R]*Derivative[2][f][R])/R^2))/
         Sqrt[(f[R]^2*Derivative[1][f][R]^2)/R^2])) == 0,
BC1 == 0,BC2 ==0
   },
    f, {R, 1, 2}]
```

Comment: Your second and third equations don't seem to be of the form f[1]stuff and f[2]otherstuff and are instead just f[R]stuff and f[R]otherstuff. If you substitute in constants instead of R then it might correctly understand that you mean those two to be boundary conditions.

Comment: Thanks Bill. One more error.

Comment: You are using e5 and NDSolve demands that all variables other than those you are solving for have been previously given constant numeric values. I tried using e5=1; Next, in the forest of denominators you have it looks like at least a couple of them can be zero, but I haven't been able to track down exactly which ones. I tried eliminating denominators from BC1 and BC2 and that didn't help. So it is probably somewhere in the DE itself. Does your system give you any chance of writing the DE in another way that might eliminate some of those denominators?

Comment: as a preliminary, discard those nasty bc's and see if you can get solutions with specified `f,f'` at `1`